# nextJS nested Routes for multiple slug cases

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

Hello everyone I have a problem regarding nextJS routing
[i have the following folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev3vt.png) and its works fine for a simple scenario where a project has only one folder and this folder have one domain
but my problem occurs when a project has a folder and this folder have many subfolders

for example if i have this URL projects/1/folder1/subfolder1/subsubfolder1/.../domain1

so as you can see i don't know how many slugs i will have
how can I achieve this??

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

> Dynamic routes can be extended to catch all paths by adding three dots (...) inside the brackets.

It means you can create a file with name `[...folder].js` and in that file, you can write your logic to handle the route.

You can even make it optional by including the parameter in double brackets ([[...folder]]). This allows `/base`, `/base/a`, `/base/a/b`, and so on.

To access `folder` object you can simply get it from `query` as

```js
{ "folder": ["a", "b"] }
```